# Relating PhoneGap, AngularJs, Ionic, Bootstrap, Jasmine, Grunt, Bower.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, gruntjs, ionic-framework

I'm starting an new project targeting mobile development, and I found my self lost on many framework options.

Specifically, I choose to do an Ionic project, which is based on Bootstrap, Phonegap, and AngularJs. To build and dependencies I'm using Grunt and Bower, and Jasmine for tests.

So, can anybody give a light on how I start the project? Which framework I use to generate the folders organization. And maybe, some tips about the relation between these tools.

Thanks!

Comment: Any reason why you need Bootstrap?

Comment: It's just the Ionic framework is based on it. And maybe I could do an project using only the angular and bootstrap, targeting browsers. I am searching ways to start multi-framework projects.

Comment: Ionic is based on Angular, but not bootstrap. You don't need bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me introduce another term for you - [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/). Yeoman is a tool for scaffolding applications, which is what you want to do. There is a yeoman generator called [generator-ionic](https://github.com/diegonetto/generator-ionic) which sounds like almost exactly what you are looking for. After installing the generator, you just run the `yo ionic` command to scaffold out your directory structure. It also automatically runs Bower to install any dependencies. The documentation for generator-ionic does a pretty good job of explaining how to get up and running, but feel free to ask if you have any questions.

Comment: I already heard about it, but though it was one more framework to worry about. I will surely take a look at it. There is any other recomendation or this stack seems fine to you?